# invalid json trace with jquery ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        headers: { "cache-control": "no-cache" },
        url: '/Service.asmx/ProcessRequest',
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        data: 'controller=cart&add=1&ajax=true&qty=' + ((quantity && quantity != null) ? quantity : '1') + '&id_product=' + idProduct + '&token=' + static_token + ((parseInt(idCombination) && idCombination != null) ? '&ipa=' + parseInt(idCombination) : ''),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (jsonData, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        }
         error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          alert(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
         }
```

server function :

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string ProcessRequest(string controller, int add, bool ajax, int qty, int id_product, string token, string ipa)
{
    string results = "{" + CartControllerResponse() + "}";
    return results;
}
```

i am getting an ajax error like this : `{"Message":"Invalid JSON primitive: controller.","StackTrace":" at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializePrimitiveObject()\r\n at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializeInternal(Int32 depth)\r\n at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.BasicDeserialize(String input, Int32 depthLimit, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)\r\n at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize[T](String input)\r\n at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData)","ExceptionType":"System.ArgumentException"}`

what am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data you are sending is invalid JSON. It should be in this format:

```
{"controller":"cart","add":1, "ajax":true ...}
```

But you are sending it in this format:

```
 data: 'controller=cart&add=1&ajax=true ...
```